# command to STOP sending form

Tags: php

I have a little problem.. the command to stop sending form to next site in a html php document.

```
<?php
echo "<br />
&lt;form action='quest2.php' name='quest1' method='post'&gt;<br/>
&lt;input type='radio' name='server' value='0'/&gt;<br />
&lt;input type='radio' name='server' value='1'/&gt;<br />
&lt;input type='radio' name='server' value='2'/&gt;<br />
&lt;input type='radio' name='server' value='3'/&gt;<br />
&lt;input type='radio' name='server' value='4'/&gt;<br />
<br />
&lt;input type='submit' name='next' value='next'/&gt;<br />
&lt;/form&gt;<br />
";

if(isset($_POST['next']) && empty($_POST['server']))
    {
        // command to stop sending form;
    }
?>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: is that php code? if so can you just copy and paste the code as it is without trying to format like this?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, want you want to do is kill the script. That is accomplished with `exit;`

So:

```
if(isset($_POST['next']) && empty($_POST['server']))
{
    // Do stuff
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to cancel the form submition you need to use javascript onsubmit event, this is an example using jquery:

index.html

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
<div id="other">
    Trigger the handler
</div>
```

script.js

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
    alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

note the use of event.preventDefault(), is the one used to cancel the form submition
read more on http://api.jquery.com/submit/